# Prediction intervals practical use cases in time series

Tags: regression, time-series, predictive-models, model, prediction-interval

i've been encountering a lot prediction intervals in regression and time series  analysis to evaluate uncertainty about predictions , i'm using it in my time series forecasts , and i wanna know exactly how to get benefit from it , to assess my model fit ,it'll be nice from you if you can provide some practical examples with some code or something , thank you !

Comment: The set of ways to get benefit from some mathematical approach is generally not well-defined and involves a messiness that cannot be made exact in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like a highest-density prediction interval it tells you about the probable range of outcomes. If it is really wide then there is quantifiable uncertainty indicating that is very difficult to predict what is going to approximately happen. In other words, it tells you how precise to expect the model to be in terms of quantifiable uncertainty.

One of the applications of prediction intervals is resource planning under uncertainty. Suppose you are forecasting the amount of resources you are going to need. You could use the conditional expectation, but the upper bound of a 99% prediction interval can give you some sense of the greatest amount of resources you'll *probably* (in the sense of 99% PI) need. It is more robust to risk to probably have enough resources than to have enough resources on average.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and you time  , i think now things became more clear because my goal is to understand and do data science not code at first place .